# auto.arima cannot offer best model lowest aic

Tags: arima, aic

I am analyzing [this data.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RKRuma_F0AF_8J_KkfkF1v-7UcRgH1R89S_p8eVUgBg/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is my code

```
library(fpp)
library(urca)

setwd("C:/Users/kuco/Desktop") #where is the file folder

dt<-read.csv("test.csv",header = FALSE) #read the file

t<-ts(dt,start = c(1997,1),frequency = 12) #put it into time series data

fit1<-auto.arima(t,stepwise = F,approximation = FALSE,ic="aic",D=1) #find the best model    
fit1 #show the best model

fit2<-arima(t,order=c(1,1,2),seasonal = list(order=c(1,1,1)))    
fit2
```

But it turns out that the `arima(1,1,2)(1,1,12)[12]` is better than the model from `auto.arima()`. So what can I do to get the lowest AIC model?
[image]

Comment: You cannot directly compare the AIC for models with different integration orders. Thus your AIC comparison does not tell which model is actually better.

Comment: i select minimize the aic when using the auto.airma, it should give the model with the lowest aic. :>

Comment: If you check the algorithm behind `auto.arima`, you will see that AIC is used within a fixed order of integration, but not across them. The order of integration (seasonal and simple) is determined by tests (OCSB and KPSS, respectively).

Comment: Your SMA coefficient  (-.7706  or -.8901) suggests possible unwarranted seasonal differences as it is in the neighborhood of -1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you cannot compare AIC values between models with different orders of differencing.

For that reason, the order of differencing is not chosen by AIC in `auto.arima`. Instead, unit root tests are used.

Even after the differencing is selected, the model returned will not necessarily have the minimum AIC because various other checks are done to ensure the model is well-behaved and numerically stable. For example, the model you fit is returning `NaN` values for some standard errors -- a sign of numerical instability in the likelihood. Such a model would never be returned by `auto.arima`. It also avoids models that have roots close to the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you so much! I learn the forecasting from your online textbook.